# Default ordering the result of a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables: menu and tax. 
I use left outer join without "order by". So are there any rule for the ordering of the result?

```
select * from menu M 
left outer join tax T
on M.tax_code = T.tax_code
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite might have a default behavior for ordering, but in general you should not rely on it.  Instead, *always* include an `ORDER BY` clause if you expect a certain order in the result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM menu m
LEFT JOIN tax t
    ON m.tax_code = t.tax_code
ORDER BY
    <some_column>;
```

Even if SQLite appears to have a default sorting order, this could change if the query/data changes later on, or if you port your query to another database.

Comment: Do you have any document about this problem? Because my application has been released so I can't modify code now and I have to report the result to my manager.

Comment: If you were just selecting from a single table, then the default sorting order _might_ use the primary key column.  But, given that you are doing a join, I don't know what the default would be.  You can test out the query and see for yourself, but in any case the best thing to do would be to ask your manager to allow you to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: One test you can try is to run your query in a SQLite browser and set the following pragma ... PRAGMA reverse_unordered_selects = 1;
This will reverse the order of selects for which there is no specific order. If using this pragma causes the result to change order then your select has an ordering that you cannot rely on.